# How to take mean of all the channels in a layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a model that returns (None,56,56,64) as it's output, as of now im taking

```
np.mean(tensor, axis=3)
```

which returns the flattened array over features (shape: None, 56,56,1), im planning to add this operation in the model itself.

As of now, I'm just adding a Conv2d layer with filter as 1, but any other way of flattening(mean) over features is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try wrapping the avg operation inside a Lambda layer:

```
imgs = np.random.uniform(0,1, (32,56,56,64)).astype('float32')

Lambda(lambda x: tf.expand_dims(tf.reduce_mean(x, axis=-1), -1))(imgs)
```

this returns a tensor of shape (batch_dim,56,56,1)

Comment: Works. Thank you!